# Pass value from an int variable in one class to another class

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying pass an int variable from one activity class(A) to another activity class(B). As I am a beginner, I am stuck here.

I have tried many methods but each time I run the code in debug mode , I can see that the int value which I have passed into the second class turns to 0.

Code for Activity A

```
   public void startMainActivity(View view)
   {
       //Sending the semester value to Navdrawer
       Intent intentsem = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavDrawer.class);
       intentsem.putExtra("UserSemester", usersemester);
       startActivity(intentsem);


       //Sending the branch value to Navdrawer

       Intent intentbranch= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavDrawer.class);
       intentbranch.putExtra("UserBranch", userbranch);
       startActivity(intentbranch);



   }
```

Code for Activity B

```
public void startSyllabusactivity(View view)

{
    // for first year

    int semester = getIntent().getIntExtra("UserSemester", 0);
    if (semester==1 || semester==2) {
        Intent l = new Intent(this, firstyear_syllabussubject_selector.class);
        startActivity(l);
    }


    //rest of the actions with branches to be added***********************

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code also for us to locate your exact problem.

Comment: You are using intent or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Intent:
Activity A:

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                 intent.putExtra("my_value", 2); //2 is the value you want to pass
                 intent.putExtra("UserBranch", userbranch);
                 startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Activity B:

```
int variable = getIntent().getIntExtra("my_value", 0);//0 is the default value if the getintExtra doesn't find the "my_value"
int userBranch= getIntent().getIntExtra("UserBranch", 0);//0 is the default
```

Comment: I can't use 'startActivity(intent);' as I don't want to start activity B as soon as the value is passed. There is a special dedicated DONE button for that purpose. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You put the code in the OnClick method of your done button

Comment: Still the value turns to be 0 when it reaches the second activity.
I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: In the code it seems that your are launching same activity two times

Comment: And in second one you are putting intentbranch.putExtra("UserBranch", userbranch); so try with "UserBranch" to get the int instead of "UserSemester"

Comment: It's working !
But how can I make it work with "UserSemester" ?
I need both the values for processing.

Comment: ok, you can pass two parameter in one intent, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `intent.putExtra()` method, for example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("myInt", myInt);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it in `ActivityB` by :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
  int value = extras.getInt("myInt");
  //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

Oh as a reminder, you should look up your question first on Google or directly at SO, as your question is a quite general one and you can dodge that negative vote..

Comment: I believe `getIntExtra` has an additional parameter, no?

Comment: Noob here. Searched a lot of questions. But understood that the mistake was on my side. Apologise!

Answer (score 1):

For this you are supposed to use *Intent*. You can get idea from below codes;

Suppose you have int variable as;

```
int x = 2;
```

Put this code in the Activity from where you want to go to another Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("xVar", x);
startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity use this code;

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int xVal = i.getIntExtra("xVar", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("value", (int)100);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

in second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value= extras.getInt("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("intValue",100);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
  int value = extras.getInt("intValue");
  //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared preferences to take care of this issue.

**In Activity A:**

int no=1;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString("my_number", no+"");

editor.commit();

**In Activity B:**

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

String m_no = prefs.getString("my_number", null);